# Simple SQL task

Tags: sql

Two Tables

Table name = profiles

| UserRefID | Firstname | Surname | Deceased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100567 | John | Smith | 0 |

Table name = emails

| UserRefID | emailID | emailaddress | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100567 | 567 | j.smith@zmail.com | 1 |

Write a short SQL select statement to retrieve all duplicate email addresses for the same UserRefID where the user is alive and at least one of the emails is a default email address.

(The deceased and default fields are both Boolean)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, let's see what you've got so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by 'duplicate' email addresses? Should provide more records for example data as well as desired output. Show attempted SQL statement. At the very least show a query that joins tables and uses a WHERE clause.

Comment: Why does it have to be short?

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.UserRefID, e.emailaddress
from profiles as p inner join emails as e on e.UserRefID = p.UserRefID
where p.Deceased = 0
group by p.UserRefID, e.emailaddress
having count(*) > 1 and max(cast("Default" as int)) = 1
```